# How to automatically detect text file charset and convert it to UTF-8

Tags: windows-7, text-editing, subtitles, character-encoding, utf-8

Is there any way to auto-detect character encoding of a text file and convert it to UTF-8? I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) if you are on Windows. Have a look at [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256049/notepad-converting-ansi-encoded-file-to-utf-8) for an example of how to do it.